# Sorting places by distance - Android

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Google places API for writing my android app.  I want to get a list of places close to current location of the device based on prominence(i.e I do not want to pass "keyword" or "type" or "name" parameter in my URL). Is there a way to do this?

According to the following link, you have to pass keyword, name or type parameter in the URL. 
https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features

I searched google and quite many threads on stackoverflow, but could not find much useful help in using rankby=distance parameter. I would appreciate it if you could share your experiences on sorting places by distance using google places API.

Thank you for your help.

NOTE: 
The following URL fails:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.787930,-122.4074990&rankby=distance&sensor=false&key=

Answer (score 0):

Keyword, Type and Name are all optional parameters. You only need to pass your API Key, Location and sensor. See the following link for details:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: You also would have to pass the distance you want the search radius to be, up to 50,000 meters. For example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere